# EF link table with 3 foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

User can have access to many associations. For a given user, I need to assign a job role to each association that he has access to. How do I map the tables in EF code first?

```
[User] 
UserId

[Association]
AssocId

[Role]
RoleId

[LNK_User_Assoc_Role]
UserId   [PK]
AssocId  [PK]
RoleId   [FK]
```

Updated:
I think octavioccl is correct, but how I assign Assoc to users? This is my code. It is not willing to work:

```
_user = new USER();
_user.Username = user.Username

DbContext.USERS.Add(_user);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

var newUser = DbContext.USERS.Find(_user.User_Id);                                               

foreach (int assocId in select2)
{
LNK_UserRoleAssoc u = new LNK_UserRoleAssoc();                           
u.User = newUser;
u.Association = DbContext.Associations.Find(assocId);
u.Role = DbContext.ROLES.Find(2);
newUser.UserRoleAssocs.Add(u);                          
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you need.

1. Using [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx):

   ```
   public class User{

     [Key]
     public Guid UserId {get;set;}

     public virtual ICollection<UserRoleAssociation> UserRoleAssociations {get;set;}      
   }

   public class Role{
     [Key]
     public Guid RoleId {get;set;}

     public virtual ICollection<UserRoleAssociation> UserRoleAssociations {get;set;}
   }

   public class Association{
     [Key]
     public Guid AssociationId {get;set;}

     public virtual ICollection<UserRoleAssociation> UserRoleAssociations {get;set;}
   }

   public class UserRoleAssociation{

    [Key,ForeignKey("User"),Column(Order=1)]
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}

    [Key,ForeignKey("Role"),Column(Order=2)]
    public Guid RoleId {get;set;}

    [Key,ForeignKey("Associoation"),Column(Order=3)]
    public Guid AssociationId {get;set;}

    //Navigation Properties

    public virtual User User {get;set;}
    public virtual Role Role {get;set;}
    public virtual Association Association {get;set;}
   ```

   }
2. Using [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx). In this case you don't need to use any attribute in the model I show above (delete them), just override the `OnModelCreating` method on your context and add these configurations:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAssociation>()
       .HasKey(c => new {c.UserId, c.RoleId, c.AssociationId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAssociation>()
       .HasRequired(p => p.User)
       .WithMany(u => u.UserRoleAssociations)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAssociation>()
       .HasRequired(p => p.Role)
       .WithMany(r => r.UserRoleAssociations)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAssociation>()
       .HasRequired(p => p.Association)
       .WithMany(a => a.UserRoleAssociations)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.AssociationId);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this is correct, but how I assign Assoc to users? This is my code. It is not willing to work:

Answer (score 0):

EF will generate the FK's based on the relationship of the objects.

```
public class User{
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public Role Role {get;set;}
    public Association Association {get;set;}
}

public class Role{
    public Guid RoleId {get;set;}
}

public class Association{
    public Guid AssociationId {get;set;}
}
```